# Is there an easy way to make HttpResponse repeatable?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I want to make a http request and then return the HttpResponse object. As far as I understand this won't work if I properly close the HttpClient object because the stream will be closed when another method tries to getEntity() of the returned response object.

**Is there a way to force a HttpResponse object to persist the response and cache it?**

This is an example method:

```
static HttpResponse get(String url) throws IOException {
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        // do something here to persists the http response
        return httpResponse;
    }
}
```

so that another method can do this:

```
void anotherMethod() {
    HttpResponse httpResponse = Utils.get("http://domain.com/site");
    String responseString = IOUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent());
}
```

I know that this can be done using the fluent interface. For my use case I need to do some modifications to the DNS resolution so I can't use the fluent interface.

Comment: Err, don't close the `HttpClient`? You don't really need this method at all, it adds no value.

Comment: @EJP What about freeing the resource?

Comment: Probably what you want is HttpClient Cache http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient-cache/apidocs/index.html